# Using conditional formatting to compare multiple cells in one row to another

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to figure out what formula I can use to highlight duplicates in a spreadsheet.

I want to compare data across multiple cells to see if it matches with other sets of cells with the same data.

For example, given this data:

**Name**,    **Food**,    **Animal**

Donald,     Hamburger,      Alligator

Rupert,  Sushi,     Alligator

Christie, Hamburger,    Panda

Donald,  Hamburger, Alligator

I want to make excel highlight the 1st and 4th cells as all values are the same across all three cells. I've tried countif to create rules to highlight the duplicate cells but I cannot seem to get excel to compare across three cells. Is the only solution to use IF AND to compare each column one by one? The data set is several hundred rows long so I am trying to figure out a quick way I can repeat this check across multiple workbooks. I've tried to use the basic conditional formatting options provided by excel but haven't been able to get a good result using those.

Thank you!

Comment: How about making a fourth column that combines the three, then comparing those values?  There's a Concatenate() function for that.

Answer (score 1):

If `Name` is in A1, please try a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$100,$A1)>1,COUNTIF($B$1:$B$100,$B1)>1,COUNTIF($C$1:$C$100,$C1)>1)
```

with Applies to: `=$A:$C`.